# Куда в файл JavaScript вставлять проверку на браузер?

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка

Делаю простенький сайт с адаптивным дизайном через `Adobe Edge Animate`. В папке сайта имею три файла JavaScript: `index_edge`, `index_edgeActions` и `index_edgePreload`.

Скачал код для проверки на браузер (взял здесь http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

Вопрос мой таков: в какой из трёх файлов и куда именно следует добавить (ну, или хотя бы, куда точно не стоит) код проверки на браузер?

Answer (score 1):

Положи исходник в ту же папку и подключи с помощью тега `script` перед подключением твоих скриптов.